False warning: CS8602 Warning despite Null Check in Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 6.0)
I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio 2022 (C# .NET 6.0) where it is giving a CS8602 warning ("Dereference of a possibly null reference") even after a null check is performed. Here is the code snippet:
public interface IParameter
{
    public string? Input { get; set; }
}

public static class FalseWarningTest
{
    public static string[] SeeTheFalseWarning(this IParameter parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.Input))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Input must have value");
        }

        return parameter.Input.Split(':');
    }
}

Despite the check for null or whitespace on parameter.Input before it is used, Visual Studio is still warning that it could be possibly null at the point where it's used.

However, when I explicitly check for null (which should be redundant), the warning disappears:
public static string[] SeeTheFalseWarning(this IParameter parameter)
{
    if (parameter.Input == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.Input))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Input must have value");
    }

    return parameter.Input.Split(':');
}

I understand that the CS8602 warning is a feature to prevent null reference exceptions. But, Is this a bug in this case since the null and whitespace checks are performed before using parameter.Input, or am I misunderstanding something?
Edit #1:
Setting the local variable and performing null/whitespace still throws the same CS8602 warning, as seen in the screenshot below.

Edit #2:
I've noticed that the code is written under .NET Standard 2.0. Upon testing the same code in .NET 6, I didn't receive the same warning from the compiler. Given that I'm not a fan of using the null-forgiving operator, the workaround string input = parameter.Input ?? string.Empty; could be the safe and straightforward way to manage the warning.

I am not able to repro this. Even an online compiler doesn't show this warning. You can see the warning if you reverse the logic in the if check.

Thank you for testing it. I'm not surprised you weren't able to reproduce the same issue in your environment, as I've never encountered this before. This is why I suspected the problem originated from Visual Studio.

Perhaps try restarting Visual Studio or even updating it.

What is your Visual Studio 2022 version? Have you tried tools->reset option?

You mention the code is under .NET Standard 2.0. That version does not officially support nullable reference types. While it can be enabled by forcing a C# 8 version, the BCL-level support is not present. That means the String.IsNullOrWhitespace's parameter will not be annotated with [NotNullWhen(false)]. Therefore, the nullable analysis will not work in this case as the compiler is not able to deduce the effects of IsNullOrWhitespace on nullability. You could roll your own + your own NotNullWhenAttribute to have this work but it seems like an overkill.

Yes, you misunderstand something. That is the devilish things people can do with C# that you don't expect :)
You are checking a getter not a local variable. A getter is not required to return the same value on two different calls. Lets build a class that kills your "null check":
public class DestroyYourNullCheck : IParameter
{
    private bool checked = false;

    public string? Input 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(checked) return null; // boom

            checked = true;
            return "NonNullString";
        }
        set {}
    } 
}

Oopsie.. but it wasn't null. Really, it wasn't when you checked. Just after that...
For your compiler to trust a null-check, it has to be something that cannot change between the check and the usage. The most obvious would be a local variable, since that is easy to assess whether it changed.
So your check should look like this:
public static string[] SeeTheFalseWarning(this IParameter parameter)
{
    var input = parameter.Input; // local variable, getter evaluated exactly once

    // local variable null checked
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Input must have value");
    }

    // compiler knows for sure local variable cannot possibly have changed since the null check:
    return input.Split(':');
}


Unfortunately, I still get the same CS8602 warning when I set the local variable  string? input = config.Server; and perform the null/whitespace check.

Did you swap both usages of the getter for the variable?

The method SeeTheFalseWarning has to take an interface as the parameter, therefore, it really doesn't matter what you do in the actual implementation.

Yes, this implementation only shows you what someone could do, and why in good null-safe systems your check would not be accepted. C# has a hybrid system due to issues with backwards compatibility and is not as sound as I would like, so it might even let it pass. But the code is to demonstrate why the null check you had first is not a valid null check at all.

While it's true that a property might return different, even null value on each access, the C# compiler's nullable analysis does not take this into the account and does not produce CS8602 because of this. Also, the provided code does not compile (checked is a keyword). While this answer raises a great point, it does not answer the question.

The code is under .NET Standard 2.0. That version does not officially support nullable reference types. While it can be enabled by forcing a C# 8 version, the BCL-level support is not present. That means the String.IsNullOrWhitespace's parameter will not be annotated with [NotNullWhen(false)]. Therefore, the nullable analysis will not work in this case as the compiler is not able to deduce the effects of IsNullOrWhitespace on nullability.
